# SASS and simple Math (Addition) of two EM units

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

For whatever reason, I can never get simple math functions straight in SASS. I have a situation where I want to add twice the gutter width to a width that I have already defined somewhere else. Both widths are in EMS, but it seems that the addition I am doing treats them as strings. Here are some things that I tried:

```
$width: 18.75em; /* 300px */
$grid-spacing: 2em; 

.column { margin-right: $width + $grid-spacing*2; }
```

Results in `.column { margin-right: 18.75em2em; }`

```
.column { margin-right: $width + ($grid-spacing*2); }
```

Results in `.column { margin-right: 18.75em2em; }`

```
.column { margin-right: $width + #{$grid-spacing*2}; }
```

Results in `.column { margin-right: 18.75em + 2em; }`

```
.column { margin-right: #{$width + #{$grid-spacing*2} };
```

Results in `.column { margin-right: 18.75em + 2em; }`

```
.column { margin-right: #{$width} + #{$grid-spacing*2}; }
```

Results in `.column { margin-right: 18.75em + 2em; }`

So what am I missing here? [According to an issue on the SASS Github](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/533), I shouldn't have to rely on clearing units from values before doing math with them. The problem, I think, is that the `+` operator is used for concatenation as well as math, and this might be why my values are being treated like strings and not numbers that can be added together.

Thoughts?

Comment: I can't get this to fail, using `sass --scss` from the command line, or at http://sassmeister.com/.  Either way, I end up with `margin-right: 22em;`  Can we see a short piece of *valid* SCSS/SASS that fails?  The example above isn't valid, of course, since `margin-right` isn't inside a selector.

Comment: Working example: https://gist.github.com/paulroub/7591492

Comment: This works as expected for me as well. Are you using an old version of SASS? I also tried switching around character encoding of my test file and it was still okay.

Comment: I'm running Compass 0.12.2. I can't seem to find out which SASS version is included. I can run:
`$ which sass` and get
`/Users/jhogue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/sass` 
but when I try `sass help` or `sass version` I get errors: 
`$ sass version` `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - version`

Comment: Interesting, my first two examples work at sassmeister.com, but the rest of the examples work as I outlined. None of them work in my version of Compass, so I guess that has to be the answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I am running SASS 3.2.6, apparently. The command is `$ sass -v`

Comment: 3.2.12 is the current release, so I'm not THAT far off. Sassmeister runs 3.3.1 right now, which is bleeding edge.

Comment: "The problem, I think, is that the + operator is used for concatenation as well as math" <- this is only true if any of the values involved are strings.  Numbers always treat `+` as addition.

Comment: works fine for me too, Compass 0.12.2

Answer (score -1):

Re the [Sass ChangeLog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html), v3.2.8 fixes some things which **might** be causing your issue.  So try updating your version of Sass:

```
gem install sass
```

If that doesn't give you version 3.2.12 when you `sass -v`, then uninstall and re-install Sass:

```
sudo gem uninstall -Iax sass
sudo gem install sass --pre
```

Your example works fine, and compiles to:

```
.column {
  margin-right: 22.75em;
}
```

Example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7780591